# How to implement 'not exists' in java

Tags: java, sap-ase

Let's say I have a huge table with around 40 million rows. I want to select rows that are not duplicate. I have already tried running a query with group by having count equal to 1 and was not happy with the performance. Is there a better way that I can implement this in java?

Comment: When we're talking a single aggregating query on a table with 40 million rows, there is absolutely nothing that you could implement in Java better than in RDBMS: transferring these rows to memory is going to kill you. But if you post your query along with query plan, and re-tag the question for SQL, you may get some useful answers.

Comment: I am not sure how an rdbms system would solve this problem but i am assuming this is done in a single threaded fashion. Do you think that by harnessing multiple threads in java this can be done faster?